# Typesort Shellscript in Unix

Tags: bash, shell

Im new to this whole Shellscript writing, so I hope for some help with a simple script.
What I want to do is to sort files in a folder/directory by their type given out by the 'type' command in Linux.
I want to filter the output of the file command using grep (to only sort after the ':''whitespace' for example, ASCII text or XML 1.0 document etc.)
I want to implement these sort types:

sort only text files using -t option
sort only non-text files using -n option
sort in reverse order using -r

I wanted to do this using a while loop with a shift to go throug the options to only need to look at one input($1)
For the diverse sorts my idea was to do 3 functions that are used in the main while loop.

So below there is my code and my main problem is to implement the sort functions the correct way:

So if you have any recommendations for me or some solutions to this I would appreciate it.

Thanks for your help and replies.

```
#A shell script with in- and output
#22.10.19

usage()
{
cat <<EOF
    $typesort [OPTIONS] FILE [ FILE ... ]
        Sort filenames by file type given by 
        the ''file'' command
    $typesort --version Print version number
   OPTIONS:
   -t           sort text files only
   -n           sort non-text files only
   -r           reverse sort order
   -v --verbose print debugging messages
EOF
}
# ----------------------------------------------

t = "-t"
n = "-n"
v = "-v"
tr = "-tr"
nr = "-nr
# -------------------------------------------------

sort_t() 
{
    sort -t':' -k 2 | grep -rI "\ASCII text\" < file *
}
# #######################################################


sort_n() 
{
    sort -t':' -k 2 | grep -r -v "ASCII text" < file *
}
# #######################################################

sort_r() 
{

}
# #######################################################

# main

while [] 
    do
        if [ $1 == t ]
            then
                sort_t
                break
        elif [ $1 == n ]
            then
                sort_n
                break
        elif [ $1 == r ]
            then 
                sort_r
                break
        elif [ $1 == v ]
            then
                echo "wrong input try again"
        else
            #at least 1 arg, let's check it
            case $1 in 
                "-h" | "--help") #display help text
                usage
                ;;
                "--version") #display version number
                echo "version number 0.1"
                break
                ;;
                *) #anything else not valid
                echo "invalid option"
                ;;
            esac
        fi
        shift
    done

exit 0
```

Comment: what is the point of sorting files' names based on their content?

Comment: This is mainly for testing purposes to unterstand how to sort files baes on a command like file. And for testing I have a multiple files and some of these don’t have endings like txt so I need to check which type these are to sort them correctly.     So is my main idea of writing this script good? Or do I have problems in it?   @JerryJeremiah So basically I can run any of these commands to sort the files by their type? So my command for the sort_t() function was nearly correct?  Sorry for such beginner questions but this is the first script I’m trying to write

Comment: This is pretty ambitious for a first script. The real question is does it have any utility for your (besides learning?. As is, it seems you have a good grasp of the basics of shell scripting, except you need a "she-bang" line at the top, usually `#!/bin/bash`. You could paste your "she-bang"ed code at https://spellcheck.net and it will probably warn you to dbl-quote a variables and a few other things. So I say, you're ready to go out and cause trouble ;-) Just remember for projects to work on test data before you unleash a possibly buggy script on your family photo archive! Good luck.

Comment: @DrDeadbrain : _by their type given out by the 'type' command_ .... aside from the fact that `type` does not tell you whether or not the file is ASCII text (the command to find out this information is `file`, not `type`),  I don't see in your script that you actually determine the type.

Comment: @shellter Besides learning how to use such commands there is no real use for me. I just came about this idea by walking through a few directories with data and so I decided to do a test folder with multiple datas.

Comment: @user1934428 Sorry. It was a little late yesterday. the file command is the one I wanted to use. And jeah there is the problem. I know how to write the command until I need to say, that it should use file on the data , so I write something like above in my code: sort -t’:’ -k2| grep-rI “ASCII text” and after this I need to pass the file data to this command. Am I Right? How do I do this?

Comment: You have two separate pieces of information: The **file name** and the output from the `file` command applied to your file name. The file content (data) is not relevant for you; hence it does not make any sense to grep the file.

Comment: So how do I grep the output of the file command instead? I assume that I have to grep it because the file command does something like.   „text: ASCII text „ as Output and i want to sort after the : whitespace

Comment: @DrDeadbrain : If you just apply `file` to a list of files (such as `file *`), the output contains one line for each file: The file name (followed by a colon), some spaces, and the file classification, for instance `ASCII text`.  **This** is something you can `grep` (if you are interested only in certain classifications), and you can `sort` it (on the classification string) to group files together with the same classification.

Comment: BTW, in your attempt to do the sorting, you write something like `sort ... <file *`. This attempts to feed a file with the name `file` to `sort`, and is likely not what you want to do. To sort the output of the `file` command, do a `file * | sort ...`.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! That makes it more clear. And after the sort I can grep to lets say only sort the text files/non text files?

Comment: Or you can grep first, if you are only interested in a certain file type, and after this, I would sort the grepped line on the file name and throw away the type information (this can be done using the `cut` command).

Comment: Okay I will try this and if I cross another big problem I come back here . Thank you for your help!:)

Comment: A few other suggestions:  1) Use `getopts` for parsing command line options, it does a lot of error checking for you. Here is a good tutorial: https://sookocheff.com/post/bash/parsing-bash-script-arguments-with-shopts/. 2) Treat each option letter as a separate case in your code. Getopts knows how to split `-nr` into `-n -r`. 3) Process all command line options first, then act on the combined results.

Comment: So I managed to fix my code and it works. But now I have a little question. Right now it works like this: I run the script inside an folder and with file * | grep... | sort I use the sort on every file if not exclamated by grep, so how could it be done if I want to give typesort some files as input args and only want to sort them?       @AndrewVickers thanks i will try this with the tutorial

Comment: Can you update the OP with the current version of the code?

Comment: I think maybe it is time for a new Q. This is a really long thread to read thru and if the original code gets deleted, then readers will be really confused about what is what. Leave a link here to your new Q and we'll check it out. Good luck.

Comment: You can also include a link to this Q in your new Q, saying "here was my first version and discussion" (or similar). Good luck.

Comment: AND while I think the `grep` ideas above are good ideas, you could also do `for f in * ; do case $(file "$f") in *[Pp][Dd][Ff]* ) echo "file $f is pdf" ;; *[Tt][Xx][Tt]* ) echo "file $f is txt" ;; * ) echo "unknown file type for $f" ;; esac ; done` sort of thing. The `case..esac` can be very powerful in shell scripting, so I just wanted to make you aware of it. You use the same "wildcard" rules for each matching rule as you use for cmd-line processing, properly known as file globs. Search for Qs on that topic to learn more. Gotta go. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! My new question with updated code can be found under this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545001/how-to-pass-files-as-argument-in-shellscript